# How to pass a network instance to a consumer in a spring java application

Tags: java, spring, events

I have a spring java applicaction with a service that initializes a network.

```
package com.victor.simple.events.services;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

@Service
public class HyperledgerNetworkService {

    @Value("${fabric.wallet.path}")
    private String walletPath;

    @Value("${fabric.wallet.privateKey}")
    private String privateKeyPath;

    @Value("${fabric.wallet.x509Cert}")
    private String x509CertPath;

    @Value("${fabric.wallet.certificate.type}")
    private String certType;

    @Value("${fabric.org.msp}")
    private String mspId;

    @Value("${fabric.org.networkProfile}")
    private String networkProfilePath;

    private static final String ADMIN_LABEL = "admin";

    @Bean
    public Gateway initialize() throws IOException,CertificateException, InvalidKeyException {
        System.out.println("Initializing Gateway");

        //Load an existing wallet holding identities used to access the network.
        Path walletDirectory = Paths.get(walletPath);

        try (FileInputStream certificate = new FileInputStream(walletDirectory.toAbsolutePath()+x509CertPath);
             FileInputStream privateKey = new FileInputStream(walletDirectory.toAbsolutePath()+privateKeyPath)) {

            CertificateFactory fac = CertificateFactory.getInstance(certType);
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) fac.generateCertificate(certificate);

            PrivateKey pk = Identities.readPrivateKey(new InputStreamReader(privateKey));
            Identity identity = Identities.newX509Identity(mspId,cert,pk);
            Wallet wallet = Wallets.newInMemoryWallet();

            if(wallet.get(ADMIN_LABEL) == null)
                wallet.put(ADMIN_LABEL, identity);

            //Path to a common connection profile describing the network.
            Path networkConfigFile = Paths.get(networkProfilePath);
            System.out.println(networkConfigFile);

            //Configure the gateway connection used to access the network.

            Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder()
                    .identity(wallet,"admin")
                    //.discovery(true)
                    .networkConfig(networkConfigFile);

            return builder.connect();
        }
    }

}
```

Then i have a controller that handles the contract events on that network:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private Consumer<ContractEvent> eventConsumer;

    private final Gateway networkService;

    @Value("${fabric.channel.contract}")
    private String contractName;

    @Value("${fabric.channel.name}")
    private String channelName;

    @PostConstruct
    private void registerEvent() throws ContractException{
        System.out.println("PostConstruct registerEvent() in EventController execution start");

        //Instantiating networks and chaincodes
        Network network = networkService.getNetwork(channelName);
        Contract contract = network.getContract(contractName);

        //Capture contract events
        contract.addContractListener(eventConsumer);

    }


}
```

You can see that when an event occurs this is managed by the event consumer:

```
@Component
public class EventConsumer implements Consumer<ContractEvent> {


    @Override
    public void accept(ContractEvent contractEvent) {
        System.out.println("New event received in the EventConsumer");

        
    }

   }
```

What i want to do is to be able to pass to the EventConsumer the instance of the network so from there i can operate against that network after an event is identified.

Something like

Thanks

Comment: There is no [tag:functional-programming} here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create a bean for network.

```
@Configuration
public class FabricConfig {
    @Value("${fabric.channel.name}")
    private String channelName;

    @Bean
    public Gateway getGateway() {
        return ...;
    }

    @Bean
    public Network getNetwork(Gateway gateway) {
        return gateway.getNetwork(channelName);
    }
}
```

This bean can be used in EventConsumer class.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EventConsumer implements Consumer<ContractEvent> {
    private Network network;
```

Note that `@Autowired` annotation is not required, if you have
constructor. Spring will try to inject beans via constructor even if it is not annotated as `@Autowired`.

Unfortunatelly I was unable to verify that it works. Not having experience with Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain.